# Powershell - Workbook.OpenText with parameter FieldInfo

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to use the Workbook.OpenText passing the parameter FieldInfo but with no success

I want to open a recent created csv file(I also tried with txt extension) with the fieldinfo parameter so I can put the text format on some columns but it keeps giving me the following error:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

The code

`
$array = @(Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 1) )

```
    $MyWorkbook = $Excel.workbooks.OpenText($file,2,1,1,1,$True,$True,$True,$False,$False,$False,$False,$array)
    
    $MyWorksheet = $MyWorkbook.WorkSheets.item(1)
```

`

Many thanks for any help
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Excel, even though you specify the **comma** as field delimiter, ALWAYS looks at
what is set as the systems ListSeparator.. Even if you specify the 'Other' and 'OtherChar' parameters to use the comma, it still fails and expects a semicolon..

On my Dutch machine that is set to the semicolon `;` so even if my csv file is using commas, AND I set the below parameter to `Comma`, Excel 'translates' that to be whatever is set in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator`

For me this works when I use the semicolon character as delimiter in the input CSV file, so I need to change the format of the csv first:

```
$Delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
$file = 'D:\Test\comma.csv'  # the original comma delimited csv
(Import-Csv -Path $file) | Export-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter $Delimiter -NoTypeInformation
```

Next problem is that method `OpenText()` does not seem to return anything, explaining the error message `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`

```
# define an array of two-element arrays, in which the first element is the column number (1-based), 
# and the second element is one of the XlColumnDataType constants specifying how the column is parsed.
# see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype
$FieldInfo = @(1, 1), @(2, 1), @(3, 1), @(4, 1), @(5, 1), @(6, 1), @(7, 1), @(8, 1), @(9, 1), @(10, 2), @(11, 1)

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.Visible = $true

# there are many parameters to the OpenText() method, but as we cannot use these as Named parameters
# we will have to provide all up to and including the FieldInfo parameter.
# note that for any variant parameter you wish to omit, we use [type]::Missing
$Excel.WorkBooks.OpenText($file,                # The absolute full file path
                          2,                    # Origin: xlWindows
                          1,                    # StartRow (default 1)
                          1,                    # DataType: xlDelimited
                          1,                    # TextQualifier: xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                          [type]::Missing,      # ConsecutiveDelimiter
                          [type]::Missing,      # Tab ($true if the file is Tab delimited; default = $false)
                          [type]::Missing,      # Semicolon ($true if the file is Semicolon delimited; default = $false)
                          [type]::Missing,      # Comma  ($true if the file is comma delimited; default = $false)
                          [type]::Missing,      # Space ($true if the file is space delimited; default = $false)
                          $true,                # Other ($true if the file delimited by the OtherChar; default = $false)
                          $Delimiter,           # OtherChar (Required if Other is True; Specifies the delimiter character)
                          $FieldInfo)

# now get the workbook and worksheet in variables
$MyWorkbook  = $Excel.WorkBooks.Item(1)
$MyWorkSheet = $MyWorkBook.WorkSheets.Item(1)
```